# Do not close combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have been trying to find a viable checked combobox control (without having the ability to write one myself).  Today I found [this one on MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CheckedCombobox-Control-52dbdb37).  It seems to work fairly well, though every time you check a checkbox the combobox control closes.  To combat that I added

```
If Not Me.DroppedDown Then Me.DroppedDown = True
```

to the OnSelectedIndexChange method.  This keeps it open, but only after it closes.  Is there a way to keep the control from closing and re-opening?  It should remain open until the control loses focus.

Comment: Which Visual studio version are you using?

Comment: @Ckrempp VS2012 and the control will ultimately be used in a .NET 4.5 solution

Comment: how will it ever close if you keep it open like that?

Comment: @Plutonix When someone clicks outside of the control, or if they click the drop-down arrow again.  That part works now, but you can see it close and then re-open, which is annoying.

Comment: ah, I missed the mention of the `OnSelectedIndexChange` method (not event)

Comment: Since it is a `ComboBox` extension then you should be able to modify the `DropDownStyle` property to simple, which would force the `ComboBox` to become a standard `ListBox` like you are looking for.

Comment: @Ckrempp I do not want a standard list box.  I have a screen with a dozen or so combobox controls on it, and the users want to be able to multi-select in each of them.